# Why are some Adwords keywords recorded as (not provided)?

Tags: google-ads

Note: This question is about Adwords CPC keywords – not organic search.

In analytics when I filter Adwords clicks by *keyword*, some clicks show as (not provided).

Why is this?

And is there a way I can make it so I can see the info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google have stopped including search query data in URLs when users click on PPC ads, if they have come from SSL searches on Google.com. This means Analytics will not be able to tell what the search query was, hence (not provided)

You can still get all the information in the Adwords system, there will just be gaps in query reporting within Analytics for those specific users.

Source: http://searchengineland.com/official-google-brings-provided-ads-will-withhold-search-query-data-paid-clicks-188750

http://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/2014/04/09/paid-search-queries-not-dead